# Roboguice java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, android-espresso, roboguice

When i run my espresso test on the main activity i get this error and i can't run the test. Has anyone run into a similar issue it seems to fail on super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); but not sure why not even using roboguice at that line of code

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: roboguice.inject.AssetManagerProvider
at roboguice.config.DefaultRoboModule.configure(DefaultRoboModule.java:155)
at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:78)
at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:252)
at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:107)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:135)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:100)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
at roboguice.RoboGuice.createGuiceInjector(RoboGuice.java:186)
at roboguice.RoboGuice.getOrCreateBaseApplicationInjector(RoboGuice.java:151)
at roboguice.RoboGuice.getOrCreateBaseApplicationInjector(RoboGuice.java:90)
at roboguice.RoboGuice.getInjector(RoboGuice.java:197)
at roboguice.activity.RoboSherlockFragmentActivity.onCreate(RoboSherlockFragmentActivity.java:47)
at com.closr.closr.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:346)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Test

```
public class ApplicationTest  extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

private MainActivity mActivity;

public ApplicationTest() {
    super(MainActivity.class);
}

@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    getActivity();
}

public void testCheckText() {
    onView(withId(R.id.txtUsername))
            .check(matches(withText("Hello World!")));
}
}
```

MainActivity

```
@ContentView(R.layout.main_layout)
     public class MainActivity extends RoboSherlockFragmentActivity implements OnClickListener{
    private static final String TAG_LOG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Fragment mContent;
    public ImageView mapFragment;
    public ImageView profileButton;
    public ImageView cameraButton;
    public ImageView homeFragment;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        cameraButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camera_fragment);
        profileButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_fragment);
        homeFragment = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.home_fragment);
        mapFragment = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.map_fragment);
        mapFragment.setOnClickListener(this);
        homeFragment.setOnClickListener(this);
        cameraButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        profileButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        homeFragment.setSelected(true);
        mContent = new ImageListFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, mContent).commit();
        if (getIntent().getAction() != null){
            if(getIntent().getAction().equals("Offer")) {
                Fragment fragment = new NotificationOfferFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
                switchContent(fragment);
            }
        }
            //        SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
            //        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
           //        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
          //        menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
          //        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
          //        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
         //        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
         //        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
         //        menu.setMenu(R.layout.slidingmenu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.home_fragment:
            homeFragment.setSelected(true);
            mapFragment.setSelected(false);
            cameraButton.setSelected(false);
            profileButton.setSelected(false);
            fragment = new ImageListFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            break;
        case R.id.camera_fragment:
            homeFragment.setSelected(false);
            mapFragment.setSelected(false);
            cameraButton.setSelected(true);
            profileButton.setSelected(false);
            fragment = CameraViewFragment.newInstance();
            fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            break;
        case R.id.map_fragment:
            homeFragment.setSelected(false);
            mapFragment.setSelected(true);
            cameraButton.setSelected(false);
            profileButton.setSelected(false);
            fragment = new ImageMapFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            break;
        case R.id.profile_fragment:
            homeFragment.setSelected(false);
            mapFragment.setSelected(false);
            cameraButton.setSelected(false);
            profileButton.setSelected(true);
            fragment = new ProfileFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            break;
        }
        switchContent(fragment);
    }

    public void switchContent(Fragment fragment) {
        mContent = fragment;
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        try{
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
                this.finish();
            }else{
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?